Help with an integral over $\mathbb R^n$
Consider $u$ a vector function in $\mathbb R^n$ of variable $x∈\mathbb R^n$. If $u$ is a divergence free vector then the integral:
$$b(u)=∑_{i,j=1}^n∫_{R^n} u_i \frac{∂u_j}{∂x_i}Δu_j dx=0$$
Why is that? I was following a course on PDE, and this is related to Navier-Stokes, I attempted this for 1 hour and it didn’t work.
